# Failure to install xcodebuild/discord.js

Tags: node.js, npm, discord

I'm making a discord bot. In terminal, after I do npm install --discord.js, it says the following:

```
integer@2.1.0 install /Users/jasmine/Desktop/kookie/node_modules/integer
> node-gyp rebuild

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jasmine/Desktop/kookie/node_modules/integer
gyp ERR! node -v v12.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN kookie@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@2.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@2.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jasmine/.npm/_logs/2020-10-22T22_03_21_562Z-debug.log
```

I attempt to run node download the application, but it it's not able to be installed. If I run node.js, this is what appears:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'quick.db'
Require stack:
- /Users/jasmine/Desktop/kookie/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jasmine/Desktop/kookie/index.js:15:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/jasmine/Desktop/kookie/index.js' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the top error, this fix worked for me:

```
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)
xcode-select --install
```

For the bottom one, it looks like you're missing the quick.db npm package.
This should suffice:

```
npm i quick.db
```

Answer (score 0):

Install xcode select

```
xcode-select --install
```

and then
the bottom error can be solved with
`npm install quick.db`